# Kubernetes fails to pull Docker image from artifactoryonline.com

Tags: docker, kubernetes, artifactory

I am using Kubernetes on AWS to run a Play+AKKA Streams server.

Here is the version details:

> **Client Version**: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.4+3eed1e3", GitCommit:"3eed1e3be6848b877ff80a93da3785d9034d0a4f", GitTreeState:"not a git tree"}
>   **Server Version**: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.4", GitCommit:"3eed1e3be6848b877ff80a93da3785d9034d0a4f", GitTreeState:"clean"}

Here is my deployment script:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service-validation2
  labels:
    name: service-validation2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: service-validation2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: service-validation2
        image: company-docker-docker-local.artifactoryonline.com/service:1.0.192
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: company-artifactory
```

when executing

```
kubectl create -f deployment.yaml --record
```

My pod goes into "ImagePullBackOff" status.

Here is the events list:

- > Successfully assigned service-validation2-3890064411-98444 to
  >   ip-172-20-0-134.us-west-2.compute.internal
- > pulling image "company-docker-docker-local.artifactoryonline.com/service:1.0.192"
- > Failed to pull image "company-docker-docker-local.artifactoryonline.com/service:1.0.192": Error: image service:1.0.192 not found
- > Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "service-validation2" with ErrImagePull: "Error: image service:1.0.192 not found"

However, the image exists on the repository -- executing:

```
docker pull company-docker-docker-local.artifactoryonline.com/service:1.0.192
```

works on my machine.

Now, there are other pods running on this node.

I'm not sure this is relevant, but immediately prior to this problem, I had a bug (relating to Play's application.conf) which caused the pods to crash. But this was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you authenticated to the Artifactory Registry? It might be that you are logged in on your machine, but you need the Kubernetes cluster authenticate to it, too.

You can do this by either directly [configuring nodes to authenticate to a private repository](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/images/#configuring-nodes-to-authenticate-to-a-private-repository) or go the recommended way and [using ImagePullSecrets](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/images/#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod).

Comment: This is a good comment. But since this used to work, we already had a secret for authenticating to the remote repository. We ended up recreating the cluster (and upgrading to version 1.3.4).

Comment: Oh yeah. Seems I overlooked that part in your deploymenI. So it worked after recreating? Strange bug.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons:
1> Authentication is not happening with artifactory 
2> docker engine conflict (I had this issue) try restarting docker.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the secret put only:

```
company-docker-docker-local.artifactoryonline.com   <this is your-registry-server>

kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=<your-registry-server>
--docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-pword> --docker-email=<your-email>
```

And then declare your `img` like this

```
${your-registry-server}/{repo-name}/<image name>
```